# How to open a embedded segue controller from another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am making an app following the same design approach of this app https://github.com/Bailig/SurveyApp .

In the above GitHub project the controllers are designed in such a way like a common ViewController with ContainerView inside.And also this common ViewController is Embed Segue with the First Controller or very first page. The container view is getting replaced for all the next screens.
In the above project there is a thank you page in the last, in my app I placed a button on the thank you page. I want to open the very first page again on click of the button from thank you page. How can I do that from last page controller/FourthController?

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var currentController: UIViewController?
var pageIndex = 1
var survey = Survey()

@IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    switch pageIndex {
    case 1:
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController")
        if let fromController = currentController, let toController = nextController as? SecondController {
            toController.survey = survey
            moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: fromController, toController: toController)
            pageIndex += 1
            setButtonAndProgressLabel()
        }
    case 2:
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdController")
        if let fromController = currentController, let toController = nextController as? ThirdController {
            toController.survey = survey
            moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: fromController, toController: toController)
            pageIndex += 1
            setButtonAndProgressLabel()
        }
    case 3:
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthController")
        if let fromController = currentController, let toController = nextController as? FourthController {
            toController.survey = survey
            moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: fromController, toController: toController)
            pageIndex += 1
            setButtonAndProgressLabel()
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    switch pageIndex {
    case 2:
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstController")
        if let fromController = currentController, let toController = nextController as? FirstController {
            toController.survey = survey
            moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: fromController, toController: toController)
            pageIndex -= 1
            setButtonAndProgressLabel()
        }
    case 3:
        let nextController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController")
        if let fromController = currentController, let toController = nextController as? SecondController {
            toController.survey = survey
            moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: fromController, toController: toController)
            pageIndex -= 1
            setButtonAndProgressLabel()
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var backTapped: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    currentController = segue.destination
    if let firstController = currentController as? FirstController {
        firstController.survey = survey
    }
    setButtonAndProgressLabel()
}

func moveAndSizeChildControllers(fromController: UIViewController, toController: UIViewController) {
    fromController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    toController.view.frame = containerView.bounds

    addChildViewController(toController)
    containerView.addSubview(toController.view)

    // animatin
    toController.view.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
        toController.view.alpha = 1
        fromController.view.alpha = 0 
    }) { (completed) in
        fromController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        fromController.removeFromParentViewController()

        toController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.currentController = toController
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can manage it by using Notification**

Add in ViewController (main)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(navigateToFirstPage), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"NavigateToFirstPage") , object: nil)
}

@objc private func navigateToFirstPage() {

    pageIndex = 2
    self.backTapped(UIButton())
}
```

Add in you fourthViewController

```
// This is your button from where you need to perform action
@IBAction func thanksButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"NavigateToFirstPage"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, that's an easiest way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would better use [delegation pattern](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/). It's simple to manage and easily to understand.

On the top of FourthController after imports you need to add

```
protocol FourthControllerThankDelegate {
    func didTapYourButton()
}
```

and then add the variable inside that class

```
class FourthController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: FourthControllerThankDelegate?
    ...
}
```

then you need to call **didTapYourButton(**) inside your button action handler

```
@IBAction func thanksButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didTapYourButton()
}
```

then inside your ViewController function **nextTapped:** you need to set this view controller as a delegate to FourthController

```
case 3:
     ... // I have skipped code above 
     toController.delegate = self
     setButtonAndProgressLabel()
}
```

and finally you need to handle delegate action

```
extension ViewController: FourthControllerThankDelegate {
    func didTapYoutButton {
        pageIndex = 2
        backTapped(self)
    }
}
```

As you do that, backTapped handler will move you to first page. This is not the best way to move back. To improve that you can create a function "displayMeFirstPage" and move there part of the logic from backTapped() case: 2 and call it inside that case and inside delegate handler. There are a lot of ways to improve navigation. if you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for your answer man.Your approach and Rohit's approach both works fine. You are doing making use of delegation and Rohit is doing making use of Notification. I'm confused on whose answer I should accept.

Comment: @KunduriRaj For this current case NotificationCenter looks like appropriate thing (less code and easy to integrate), but in future in your career will not use NotificationCenter because it makes project difficult to debug and easily to make a mistake. You will only use it to listen system messages, except difficult cases where you can't do otherwise. Decision is up to you.